# Error while writing data frame to oracle with to_sql

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I try to write a data frame in an existing table in my database with "to_sql".

```
df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=eng, if_exists='append',index=True)
```

While inserting python return an error:

> DatabaseError: ORA-00932: Inconsistent data types: NUMBER expected,
>   CLOB receive

Get out the inserting statement which looks like this:

```
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, start, end) VALUES (:id, :name, :start, :end)']
[parameters: {'id': 5629, 'name': 'WNL', 'start': datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'end': '2010-01-01'}]
```

noticed that "to_sql" treats start as a datetime and end as a string. Both columns are definedin oracle as DATE type. Data frame was creating by reading a csv file. Csv file looks like:

> id;name;start;end
>
> 5629;WNL;1990-01-01;2010-01-01

exetuting df.dtypes shows:

```
id                                    int64
name                                 object
start                        datetime64[ns]
end                                  object
```

I guess the error occur because of the datatype. But converting with pandas.to_datetime() doesn't change object to datetime64[ns].

Is there an other way to change the data type or to write in the database more easier?
Please excuse if it's a stupid question. Just started to learn python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you print out the statement and parameters?